# Google Analytics - my goal event doesn't work

Tags: google-analytics

I have a goal in Google Analytics that does not work for a reason that I do not understand. Conversions are not counted.
What could be the problem?
Here's how I set the goal in the site code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="ru">
   <head>
   <!— Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics —>
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-108002615-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-108002615-1');
</script>

   </head>
   <body>
     <button onclick="gtag('event', 'best-goal-666', { 'event_category': 'Category', 'event_action': 'Action', 'event_label': 'click-button-347-2', 'value': 1});">RABOTAI BLYAT</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

[Screenshot of goal settings in google analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTobD.jpg)

Comment: Are you seeing the event in google analytics?

Comment: have you tried looking at: Reports -> Real-Time -> Conversions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out there was no problem with the code.
Google Analytics counted the conversion after three days.
So if you have similar issue just try to wait for GA's periods will finish.